# What is the name of the sound dispersion device(waveguide?) common to some omnipolar speakers?

Tags: speakers

What is the name of the devices used to disperse the sound radially.  They appear like a cone as seen in the following image.

I would like to find research on them.  I have tried searching for terms like horn, waveguide and cone.

Link to speaker site: https://hsd-studios.com/omnipolar-speaker/?lang=en
[image]

Example 2:
http://www.2pi-online.de/html/demokrit.html

[image]

Example 3:
https://eiaudio.de/gear-and-review/loudspeakers/duevel-planets/
Duevel Planets
[image]

Other examples:

Mirage OMD-5
[image]

Comment: Added multiple images of real speakers with arrows indicating the device in ea.

Comment: Cool thanks. I’ve never seen those before

Comment: I haven't been able to find a term used in more than one place for the device. Things like "dispersion cone" and "reflector" are used and make sense. In terms of research on them, they might be considered gimmicks and there might have been little interest in research to date. I can think of some audio installation situations where these might be used in a professional context, but that's not super common. Seems like these designs are currently aimed at the home audio space, not professional sound design or engineering.

Comment: Regarding research, these devices are all hallmarks of omnidirectional speaker design, so you might instead try searching for omnidirectional speaker research.

Comment: I mean they are not useful for audio engineering purposes in professional environments or for live sound reinforcement or theatre sound. In most of those situations, an omnidirectional speaker would be an acoustic nightmare. They seem to be only useful for entertainment or sound fields for outdoor ambient music or sonic art installation. Since they rely on the acoustic space, they will not be ideal for all home uses, and they seem to be a solution to a problem that doesn’t really exist. They *might* be **considered** a gimmick, for those reasons.